# set the selectedIndex of a DropDown using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to set the index of an dropdown to 0; if the user is uncheck the checkbox as show in the example but some how its just ignoring...

```
$ddlHeader.attr('selectedIndex', 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/9YM4P/

//html:

```
Header:
<br /><input id="check" type="checkbox" name="approve" />
<select id="myddl" name="myddl">
    <option value="0">select me</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Twooo</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

​

//js

```
var $ddls = $('select');
var $check = $('#check');
var $ddlHeader = $("#myddl"); 

$ddls.prop("disabled", true); 

$check .click(function() {
    $ddls.prop("disabled", true); 
    $ddlHeader.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $ddlHeader.attr('selectedIndex', 0);

});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ddlHeader.find('option:first').prop('selected', 'selected');
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/9YM4P/3/)

Update:

```
$('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Or with more code but more flexible:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Comment: just trying to understand your code... what if; if i want all (`find('select')` the dropdown to be selected to index = 0  how would you do?

Comment: I have the following and I keep getting `null`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653375/how-to-set-asp-net-dropdownlist-index-to-0-from-the-front-end

Answer (score 4):

Use `.prop` like below,

```
$ddlHeader.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YM4P/2/)

Answer (score 2):

**UPD**:

I confused `selectedIndex` and value. So this solution would work only if you explicitly want the value = 0 to be selected:

Use `val(0)` instead

```
$check.click(function() {
    $ddls.prop("disabled", true); 
    $ddlHeader.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $ddlHeader.val(0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9YM4P/1/

Comment: @zerkms No you are setting the value to `0` and works fine because corresponding option is in index 0

Comment: It doesn't change the index! it select the option with the `0` value. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/9YM4P/4/)

Comment: @Vega: yep, I confused it - +1 for your solutions

Answer (score -1):

//This line of code works for me.
`$(function(){$("select").each(function (i) {
$(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
});
});`