# How to set ASP.net dropdownlist index to 0 from the front-end

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I have the following code in ASP.net page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddl1" CssClass="chosen-select le" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddl2" CssClass="chosen-select le" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddl3" CssClass="chosen-select le" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>

<input type="button" id="ClearForm" value="Clear" class="btn1" />
```

JQuery to set the index to 0 for all three dropdownlist:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#ClearForm", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("select#ddl1, select#ddl2, select#ddl3").prop('selectedIndex', 0); //does not set the selected index to 0
        alert($("select#ddl1").text()); //displays all the options from #ddl1
    });
});
```

How can I modify so the dropdownlist index is set to 0.

HTML render of the first dropdownlist:

```
<select name="ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ddl1" id="ddl1" class="le">
    <option value="Select a State">Select a State</option>
    <option value="Alabama">AL</option>
    <option value="Alaska">AK</option>
    <option value="Arizona">AZ</option>
</select>
```

I tried the following JQuery and it returns `null`:

```
alert($("select#ddl1").val());
```

Also tried the following and it didn't work:

```
$('select').each(function () {
    $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Added the following JavaScript:

```
function setSelectedIndex(dropdownlist, selVal) {
    var ddl1 = document.getElementById(dropdownlist);
    alert(ddl1.selectedIndex);
    if (ddl1.length >= selVal) { //if the selected value is greater then 0, the alert is shown but the value is not set back to 0.
        ddl1.selectedIndex = selVal;
        alert("greater or equal");
    }
    else {
        alert("not greater or equal");
    }
}
```

It seems like, if I remove the chosen Jquery it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bpbvhsay/

Comment: you want `$('...').val(0)`

Comment: i don't think `ddl1` etc is the actual client id. Post the rendered HTML

Comment: Try  `alert($("select#ddl1").val());`

Comment: the 'correct' way is to reference it directly: `$('#<%= ddl1.ClientID %>').val(0)`

Comment: Give this a try: 
`document.getElementById('ddl2').selectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: I am using `ClientIDMode="Static"` which sets the HTML ID to that is in the DropDownList element.

Comment: Updated my question with the HTML render and the JQuery and it keeps returning `null`. I wanted to do something recursive so with one line, all the dropdownlist is defaulted to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the Chosen Jquery which caused the dropdownlist to not update.

This is the HTML:

```
<select name="ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ddl1" id="ddl1" class="chose-select le">
    <option value="Select a State">Select a State</option>
    <option value="Alabama">AL</option>
    <option value="Alaska">AK</option>
    <option value="Arizona">AZ</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript which sets the selected index to 0:

```
function setSelectedIndex(dropdownlist, selVal) {
    var ddl1 = document.getElementById(dropdownlist);
    if (selVal < ddl1.selectedIndex) {
        ddl1.selectedIndex = selVal;

        $(ddl1).val(0).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
}
```

That does the trick.

Comment: You should ask another question. Not ask questions by posting as answer. If question is similar than link each other.

Comment: @MMTac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656711/why-does-the-asp-net-dropdownlist-does-not-default-to-0-if-chosen-jquery-is-used Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this but here is the solution with JavaScript:

```
function setSelectedIndex(dropdownlist, selVal)
    var ddl1 = document.getElementById(dropdownlist);
    //alert(ddl1.selectedIndex); //displays the proper index...
    if(ddl1.length >= selVal)
    {
       ddl1.selectedIndex = selVal;
    }
}
```

Call the above function as per you required as below:

```
setSelectedIndex('<%=ddl1.ClientID %>', 2);
```

**UPDATE** As you said you have already set `ClientIDMode`, try the following updated function:

```
function setSelectedIndex(selVal){
    var ddl1 = document.getElementById('ddl1');
    if(ddl1.length >= selVal)
    {
       ddl1.selectedIndex = selVal;
    }
}
```

and call it as:

```
setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Comment: I don't have to use `ddl1.ClientID` because I am using `ClientIDMode` but I will test out your code. Thanks. Updated your code to show the issue for me.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh I see what is happening. I am using the chosen JQuery to style my dropdownlist. If I remove it works :/ Most likely chosen is interfering with it.